# NUnit ITestEventListener get output only continuously

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have a very simple TestEventListener that send output to the console and to a text file. However, it currently prints everything and I only want to capture the  event, but I'm not sure how to do it. Also, is it possible to get it as it happened? As of right now it only seems to be printing after the test is run which isn't really ideal. Here's what I have now:

```
class TestListener : ITestEventListener
{
    StreamWriter _outputStream;
    string _outputFile;

    public TestListener(string outputPath)
    {
        _outputFile = outputPath + "\\ConsoleLog.txt";
        _outputStream = new StreamWriter(_outputFile);
    }

    public void OnTestEvent (string report)
    {
        WriteText(report);
    }

    public void WriteText(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        _outputStream.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your code that's printing everything. The `report`, as you have seen, is XML. It's up to you to look at it in your code and decide what to print.

Most likely, in the events you receive, you will see test starts, test results and immediate text output if you have any. Which of those do you want to display?

As far as only getting output after the test finishes, that would be the test result output, which obviously has to come after the end of the test. It includes an element `output` with any text writes that were done in the course of the test.

If you want immediate output, which comes as a `test-output` report, you have to create it in your tests. The only output that is sent this way is Console.Error, TestContext.Error and TestContext.Progress. This is the only output that comes to you before the end of the test.

Comment: How would I go about only getting the test-output though?

Comment: You can't. You get all the events. You have to programmatically select those events you care about and ignore the rest. If you are unfamiliar with how to handle XML in C#, refer to the documentation of the XmlNode class.